# Problema com Variável POST php

Tags: php, html

Código:

***Form:***

```
<form action="../controller/NotPrecontrole.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return valid();">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
   <input type="date" name="DtInicio" value="<?php echo $DtInicio; ?>">
   <input type="submit" class="round success small button" value="Aplicar"/>
   <a class="round secondary small button" href="Home.php">Voltar</a>
</form>
```

***Precontrole:***

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$DsMsg = $_POST['Msg'];
$InAtivo = $_POST['InAtivo'];
$DtInicio = $_POST['DtInicio'];
$DtFim = $_POST['DtFim'];

$objNot = new Not();
$objNot->setid($id);
$objNot->setmsg($DsMsg);
$objNot->setativo($InAtivo);
$objNot->setini($DtInicio);
$objNot->setfim($DtFim);

$controller = new Notifica($conn);


if (!empty($id)){
   $objNot->setid($id);
   $controller->editarNot($objNot);
}

header ("location: ../view/home.php?id=".$id);
```

***Home:***

```
 <?php 
 foreach ($controller->ListaNot() as $objNot){
         echo '<li><a href="editNot.php?id=' . $objNot->getid() . '">Editar</a></li>';

    if($DtInicio == date('Y-m-d')){
      echo $objNot->getmsg(); 
   } 
}
```

Erro:

**Notice: Undefined variable: DtInicio in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rasador1\view\home.php on line 63**

Estou tentando pegar a data que vai para o POST no `$DtInicio` e comparar com a data de hoje para imprimir na tela `$objNot->getmsg();`, porém está dando o erro acima. Eu preciso dar um `Isset` e pegar ela por `GET`mas não sei como, alguma ajuda ?

Comment: Você está dando um header("location"), isso acredito que não deixe mais o valor da variavel $DtInicio. Pq não passa como parametro assim como faz com o id? Ficaria header ("location: ../view/home.php?id=".$id."&data=".$DtInicio); , ai pega ela com $_GET. Não tive tempo de testar.

Comment: Poste o formulário HTML